# How to make controllable virus simulation using turtle python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

Uh I was tasked to make a controllable Covid-19 simulation using python turtle for a school project. So what I made was a bunch of moving randomly turtles and random picked "posessed" and random picked "infected" turtles. I was trying to make the "posessed" ones controllable with arrow keys, and also picks another "healthy" turtle if the previous one got infected. The problem is, I dont know how to separate the controls as they were all tagged under the class "Person". I also don't know how to make it choose another healthy turtle when one is infected. Here is the messy code. Sorry for bad english.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
"""
This imports the screen and turtle from the turtle module
"""
from random import randint, choice
"""
This is to use the random integer function and the random choosing of the infected
"""
from time import sleep
posessed = 0
class Person(Turtle):
    population = []

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape='circle')

        self.shapesize(0.4)
        self.penup()
        self.setpos(randint(-250, 250), randint(-250, 250))

        Person.population.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def all_infected(cls):
        return [person for person in cls.population if person.infected()]

    def infect(self):
        self.color('red')

    def infected(self):
        return self.pencolor() == 'red'
    def all_infected(cls):
        return [person for person in cls.population if person.posessed()]

    def posess(self):
        self.color('yellow')

    def posessed(self):
        return self.pencolor() == 'yellow'


    def random_move(self):
        self.right(randint(-180,180))
        self.forward(randint(0,10))
        if not (-250 < self.xcor() <250 and -250 < self.ycor() < 250):
            self.undo() # this will undo forward()

def make_population(amount):

    for _ in range(amount):
        Person()

def posess_random():
    person = choice(Person.population)
    person.posess()
    posessed+1

def infect_random():
    person = choice(Person.population)
    person.infect()

def simulation():
    """ This will simulate the virus outbreak scenarios (quarantine, or not quarantine) """
    amount=int(input("Enter amount of people within the area: " ))
    moves=int(input("Enter the amount of moves these people will do: "))
    print("Entered amount of people: ", amount)
    print("Entered amount of movements: ", moves)
    make_population(amount)

    infect_random()
    posess_random()

    screen.update()
    for _ in range(moves):
        for person.infected in Person.population:
            person.random_move()

            if not person.infected():
                for infected in Person.all_infected():
                    if person.distance(infected) < 30:
                        person.infect()
                        #this is used to set distance to get infected. In this case I did 30

        screen.update()
        sleep(0.1)


screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500,500)
screen.tracer(0)
screen.bgcolor(str(input("Enter desired background color: ")))
simulation()

screen.exitonclick()
               #this should do it
```

Tysm before hand

Answer (score 1):

> So what I made was a bunch of moving randomly turtles

First, this code doesn't run as posted -- I had to fix at least three errors to get it to run.  Surprisingly since it is only has minor changes to [my rework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61643589/5771269), of [@LST_2020's code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61634600/5771269), the former of which runs fine.  And there's no credit/link back to that code!  Moving on:

Below is my rework of *our* code to fix *your* introduced bugs, and make the *possessed* person manually movable.  (Fixing the spelling of "possessed" along the way.)  And if the possessed person comes into contact with an *infected* person, either by their own motion or the infected person's motion, the possessed becomes infected and a random healthy person, if available, becomes possessed and manually moveable:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint, choice
from functools import partial
from time import sleep

INFECTION_DISTANCE = 30
PERSON_RADIUS = 8
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

possessed = 0

class Person(Turtle):
    population = []

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape='circle')

        self.shapesize(PERSON_RADIUS / CURSOR_SIZE)
        self.penup()
        self.setpos(randint(-WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2), randint(-HEIGHT/2, HEIGHT/2))

        Person.population.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def all_infected(cls):
        return [person for person in cls.population if person.infected()]

    def infect(self):
        self.color('red')

    def infected(self):
        return self.pencolor() == 'red'

    @classmethod
    def all_healthy(cls):
        return [person for person in cls.population if not person.infected()]

    def possess(self):
        self.color('green')

    def possessed(self):
        return self.pencolor() == 'green'

    def random_move(self):
        self.right(randint(-90, 90))
        self.forward(randint(0, 10))

        x, y = self.position()

        if not (PERSON_RADIUS - WIDTH/2 < x < WIDTH/2 - PERSON_RADIUS and PERSON_RADIUS - HEIGHT/2 < y < HEIGHT/2 - PERSON_RADIUS):
            self.undo()  # this will undo forward()

def make_population(amount):
    for _ in range(amount):
        Person()

def possess_random():
    possessed = None

    healthy = Person.all_healthy()

    if healthy:
        possessed = choice(healthy)
        possessed.possess()

        screen.onkey(partial(move_up, possessed), 'Up')
        screen.onkey(partial(move_down, possessed), 'Down')
        screen.onkey(partial(move_right, possessed), 'Right')
        screen.onkey(partial(move_left, possessed), 'Left')

    return possessed

def infect_random():
    person = None

    healthy = Person.all_healthy()

    if healthy:
        person = choice(healthy)
        person.infect()

    return person

def check_infection(person):
    for infected in Person.all_infected():
        if person.distance(infected) < INFECTION_DISTANCE:
            is_possessed = person.possessed()

            person.infect()

            if is_possessed:
                possess_random()

def simulation(amount, moves):
    """ This will simulate the virus outbreak scenarios (quarantine, or not quarantine) """
    make_population(amount)

    infect_random()
    possess_random()
    screen.update()

    for _ in range(moves):
        for person in Person.population:
            if not person.possessed():
                person.random_move()

            if not person.infected():
                check_infection(person)

        screen.update()
        sleep(0.1)

def move_up(possessed):
    y = possessed.ycor() + 10

    if y < HEIGHT/2 - PERSON_RADIUS:
        possessed.sety(y)
        check_infection(possessed)

def move_down(possessed):
    y = possessed.ycor() - 10

    if y > PERSON_RADIUS - HEIGHT/2:
        possessed.sety(y)
        check_infection(possessed)

def move_right(possessed):
    x = possessed.xcor() + 10

    if x < WIDTH/2 - PERSON_RADIUS:
        possessed.setx(x)
        check_infection(possessed)

def move_left(possessed):
    x = possessed.xcor() - 10

    if x > PERSON_RADIUS - WIDTH/2:
        possessed.setx(x)
        check_infection(possessed)

amount = int(input("Enter amount of people within the area: "))
moves = int(input("Enter the amount of moves these people will do: "))

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

screen.listen()
screen.tracer(False)

simulation(amount, moves)

screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

I changed the possessed color to green as I couldn't see the yellow dot easily against the default turtle background color.  And I moved the input questions ahead of the first turtle call so that the user doesn't have to click back to the console to answer them.

As I noted on my original, you should consider using turtle timer events to make the people more autonomous, instead of the `for _ in range(moves): loop` which also blocks some turtle events.

Comment: Tysm! Btw yes sorry for not giving the credit out. That actually helped me. Im being tasked to study this code. About the mistakes, I am really a beginner so... I have a lot to learn. Thank you again!